# Calculate mean and max value with VectorAssembler

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm working with a data frame, something like:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler


from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField("ClientId", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("m_ant21", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("m_ant22", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("m_ant23", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("m_ant24", IntegerType(), True)
])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
                             data=[(0, 5, 5, 4, 0),
                                   (1, 23, 13, 17, 99),
                                   (2, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                                   (3, 0, 4, 1, 0),
                                   (4, 2, 1, 30, 10),
                                   (5, 0, 0, 0, 0)],
                                   schema=schema)
```

I need to calculate the mean value an max value per row and using the columns "m_ant21", "m_ant22", "m_ant23", "m_ant24".

I'm trying using vectorAssembler:

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=["m_ant21", "m_ant22", "m_ant23","m_ant24"],
    outputCol="muestra")
output = assembler.transform(df)
output.show()
```

now, I create a function to make the mean, but the input variable is a "DenseVector" called "dv":

```
   dv = output.collect()[0].asDict()['muestra']

def mi_media( dv ) :
    return float( sum( dv ) / dv.size  ) 


udf_media  = udf( mi_media, DoubleType() )
output1 = output.withColumn( "mediaVec",  udf_media ( output.muestra ) )
output1.show()
```

and the same to the max value:

```
def mi_Max( dv ) :
        return float(max( dv )  )   
udf_max  = udf( mi_Max, DoubleType() )
output2 = output.withColumn( "maxVec",  udf_max ( output.muestra ) )
output2.show()
```

The problem is the error in output1.show() and output2.show(). Just It's not working and I dont know what happends with the code.
What am i doing wrong?
Please help me.

Comment: for each row you need mean and max or for each column ?

Comment: Yes. I need two new colums that indicates those values per row.

Comment: why do you need vector assembler for that ?

Comment: I got another way to make it, but its not efficient, because i have a lot of data!

Comment: May be you can obtain, in the max case for example, the maximun value of each row vector with RDDs: `output.rdd.map(lambda x:(np.max(x.muestra.toArray())))` and then join it with `output` data frame converted to RDD with `zipWithIndex`, where `np` is NumPy alias. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried my way, check it,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.show()
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|ClientId|m_ant21|m_ant22|m_ant23|m_ant24|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|       0|      5|      5|      4|      0|
|       1|     23|     13|     17|     99|
|       2|      0|      0|      0|      1|
|       3|      0|      4|      1|      0|
|       4|      2|      1|     30|     10|
|       5|      0|      0|      0|      0|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+

df1 = df.withColumn('mean',sum(df[c] for c in df.columns[1:])/len(df.columns[1:]))
df1 = df1.withColumn('max',F.greatest(*[F.coalesce(df[c],F.lit(0)) for c in df.columns[1:]]))

df1.show()

+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+---+
|ClientId|m_ant21|m_ant22|m_ant23|m_ant24| mean|max|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+---+
|       0|      5|      5|      4|      0|  3.5|  5|
|       1|     23|     13|     17|     99| 38.0| 99|
|       2|      0|      0|      0|      1| 0.25|  1|
|       3|      0|      4|      1|      0| 1.25|  4|
|       4|      2|      1|     30|     10|10.75| 30|
|       5|      0|      0|      0|      0|  0.0|  0|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+---+
```

Comment: Just a question: with F.greatest(*[F.coalesce, how can i use those functions?

Comment: I have edited the answer to import the functions package.

Comment: It works, and its clear. I'd like to make it with vectorAssembler, but this is a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it with DenseVector but in RDD way:

```
output2 = output.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.ClientId, 
                                   x.m_ant21, 
                                   x.m_ant22,
                                   x.m_ant23,
                                   x.m_ant24,
                                   x.muestra, 
                                   float(max(x.muestra))))
output2 = spark.createDataFrame(output2)
output2.show()
```

which gives:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+--------------------+----+
| _1| _2| _3| _4| _5|                  _6|  _7|
+---+---+---+---+---+--------------------+----+
|  0|  5|  5|  4|  0|   [5.0,5.0,4.0,0.0]| 5.0|
|  1| 23| 13| 17| 99|[23.0,13.0,17.0,9...|99.0|
|  2|  0|  0|  0|  1|       (4,[3],[1.0])| 1.0|
|  3|  0|  4|  1|  0|   [0.0,4.0,1.0,0.0]| 4.0|
|  4|  2|  1| 30| 10| [2.0,1.0,30.0,10.0]|30.0|
|  5|  0|  0|  0|  0|           (4,[],[])| 0.0|
+---+---+---+---+---+--------------------+----+
```

Now all that remains is to rename the columns, for example with `withColumnRename` function.The mean case is the same.

Also it's possible do that with `SparseVector` but, in this case, it is necessary to access to [`self` class `value` variable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.linalg-pysrc.html#SparseVector):

```
output2 = output.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.ClientId, 
                                       x.m_ant21, 
                                       x.m_ant22,
                                       x.m_ant23,
                                       x.m_ant24,
                                       x.muestra, 
                                       float(max(x.muestra.values))))
output2 = spark.createDataFrame(output2)
```

This way works better if you df has a lot of columns and it is not possible to calc max value before VectorAssembler stage.

Answer (score 0):

i get a solution about this problem

```
import pyspark.sql.functions  as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t

min_of_vector = f.udf(lambda vec: vec.toArray().min(), t.DoubleType())

max_of_vector = f.udf(lambda vec: vec.toArray().max(), t.DoubleType())

mean_of_vector = f.udf(lambda vec: vec.toArray().mean(), t.DoubleType())

final = output.withColumn('min', min_of_vector('muestra')) \
        .withColumn('max', max_of_vector('muestra')) \
        .withColumn('mean', mean_of_vector('muestra'))
```